# How to test If Else block in Angular Unit Testing using Jasmine /Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am testing a component's ngOnit() which has if and else block. The code in the .ts file looks like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this.profileSvc.loggedIn = true;

if (this.profileSvc.loggedIn) {
  this.setVars();
} else {
  this.stopSpinner();
  this.generalMessage = 'Please Log In!';
  this.displayGeneral = true;
}
this.appInsightsService.logPageView('CustomerProfile');
```

}

My tests on .spec.ts are here.
for if block:

```
  it('test ngOnInit()', () =>{
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.profileSvc.loggedIn).toBe(true);
  });
  it('test ngOnInit() when not loggedIn', () =>{
     //(mockprofileService as any).loggedIn = false;
     //spyOn<any>(mockprofileService, 'loggedIn').and.returnValue(false);
     component.profileSvc.loggedIn = false;
     component.ngOnInit();
     expect(component.displayGeneral).toBe(true);
 });
```

The first test which is for the if block got succeeded, but my second test failed which is for else block. I got this error:

```
Expected false to be true.
```

My question is how to set the value of `.profileSvc.loggedIn` to false to test the else block. Please help! I would really appreciate. Also if you can direct me to best place to learn about Jamsin, I would really appreciate it.

Edit: `profileSvc` is a service. and I have mock for it is `mockprofileService`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the line that sets the value to true in the `ngOnInit` or else it is untestable.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   // remove this line !!
  //  this.profileSvc.loggedIn = true;

  if (this.profileSvc.loggedIn) {
    this.setVars();
  } else {
    this.stopSpinner();
    this.generalMessage = 'Please Log In!';
    this.displayGeneral = true;
  }
  this.appInsightsService.logPageView('CustomerProfile');
}
```

```
 it('should call setVars if user is logged in', () => {
      (mockprofileService as any).loggedIn = true;
      const setVarsSpy = spyOn(component, 'setVars');
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(setVarsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  it('should stop the spinner and set the message if user is not logged in', () =>{
     (mockprofileService as any).loggedIn = false;
     const stopSpinnerSpy = spyOn(component, 'stopSpinner');
     component.ngOnInit();
     expect(stopSpinnerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
     expect(component.generalMessage).toBe('Please Log In!');
     expect(component.displayGeneral).toBe(true);  
 })
```